# Header Image not displaying

Tags: html, css

When I run this code it doesn't display an image in background

```
.bgimg-1 {
    background-image: url("/Images/oldcam.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: most likely your url is wrong. Try to add an <img src="your img"> and see if it displays. Then work from there. Also, this is hard for any of us to troubleshoot as it's a small snippet of code. We also don't know what your file structure looks like that houses your files.

Comment: Are you using this class in a div? Try adding the image source directly in the div first and make sure you are targeting the correct path.

Comment: No worries i fixed it. I had my directory set up wrong hahaha

Answer (score 1):

following is code :-

```css
.bgimg-1 {
  width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png");


}
```

```html
<div class="bgimg-1 w3-display-container w3-opacity-min" id="home">
```